# Letting $f(x) = e^{3x}$. How to find the $p_3(2)$, the value at $x = 2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f (x) = e^{3x}$. Find $p_3(2)$, the value at $x = 2$ of the third Taylor polynomial about $0$, and $r_3(2)$, the value at $x = 2$ of the third Taylor remainder of $f$ about $0$. $p_3(2)$ = ? 
$r_3(2) = e4 +$ ?

Please explain
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Set $3x=3(y+2)$ first. So $$f=e^{3y+6}=e^{6} e^{3y}$$ Now $3y=z$, use the classical expansion ot $e^z$ around $z=0$. When finished, replace.